# Unable to deploy XML Office App manifest to exchange account/Azure

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a pretty standard Office App Outlook Manifest to deploy an application I've made to Office 365 Admin center, to then populate it to users in my organisation.

I'm getting an error where it says that my MS account is locked (Connecting to exchange email account). I presume this is related to the fact that I have 2FA, and no way of autenticating through 2FA in VS, when compiling/deploying code.

Manifest posted below. Have anyone encountered the same issue?

If some of the data is strange it's (hopefully) because I anonymised the data.

[image]

[image]

BR
HH

Tried to deploy the manifest, but were not able to due to the following error messager: MS account is locked.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you add the manifest to the admin center manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manifest file looks good. It seems you need to enable multi-factor auth in the Office add-in project.

In Visual Studio you need to select in the `Solution Explorer` window the project with the manifest file and open the `Properties` window for it, here is how it looks like on my machine:

[image: Support for multi-factor auth in Office add-ins]

Then you need to set the `Use multi-factor auth` property to `true`. Viola!