# Deployed Office Manifest to Exchange account dosen't show up on users' web/desktop outlook clients

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Uploaded this manifest which I were having an issue with earlier to office exchange centre -  [Unable to deploy XML Office App manifest to exchange account/Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74343911/unable-to-deploy-xml-office-app-manifest-to-exchange-account-azure).

When we upload the manifest and add the app like this, it dosen't show up on either web or desktop outlook clients.

[image]

Furthermore, when I try to upload the manifest locally, it only displays a white background when I open the Add-in in Outlook.

Right now, we're hosting the files and refrencing them by URL in/to Azure blob storage.

[image]

I'm a bit new to Office Addins, and I guess the files don't get compiled correctly like this?

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

BR

HH

Note: When our Exchange Admin runs the manifest through VS, it works as inteded and he can access and use the addin. The issue with this, is that we're unable to deploy it to the rest of the org. Here we are refrencing the files in the solution, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take up to 24 hours for an add-in to show up for client for all users. So, it makes sense to wait a day until the add-in is rolled out. Make sure that you have uninstalled local copies before. Read more about that in the [Test and deploy Microsoft 365 Apps by partners in the Integrated apps portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/test-and-deploy-microsoft-365-apps?view=o365-worldwide) article.

Comment: I though so as well, but it hasn't appeared now after 24+ hours. I assume the issue it that it might not be applicable to host the function file/Message Read in Blob storage, since when I'm adding the manifest/app as a local addin, I just get a white screen?

Comment: Do you get any errors when you sideload the add-in (the same manifest file) in the host application (Outlook)?

Comment: No, but when I open it I just get a white background. I also get a white background when putting in the Azureblogstorage links in my browswer. I guess that's because the code hasn't been compiled? I'm trying to run an iFrame to run an PowerApp. 

It's working correclty when our exchange admin runs the manifest from VS and refrencing the files like this: 

~remoteAppUrl/Images/icon64.png

Comment: Thanks a lot again, Eugene. It was indeed just waiting that was necassary for it to show up, somehow it took 3 days before it showed.